# How to geocode Indian Addresses in Android program?

Tags: android, geocoding

Can anyone please help me to complete my android program in which i am entering the Address of an Indian location **(AshokNagar,Vijayawada,Andhra Pradesh,India)** in a text box

On clicking a button i must get the **latitude** and **longitude** of this location in two separate text boxes .Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using geo tagging tools. These will give you an API to get the latitude longitude for a given address. You could use this [free and open source](http://www.gisgraphy.com/) version or the [google maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Google Geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) for getting latitude and longitude values, but they will be in JSON format.

If you are using JavaScript can be easily parsed [like this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/index#ParsingJSON).

For Java, I would suggest you to use [Google JSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and for other languages see http://json.org/